# How to open Virt-manager VM from command line?

Tags: arch-linux, virtual-machine, qemu, i3, virt-manager

My system is Arch Linux 5.17.9 running i3wm.

I am trying to start a VM which is configured in Virt-Manager and Qemu.

I have tried the command,

```
sudo virsh list --all
```

this brings up the installed VMs on Virt-Manager in the terminal.

I have then tried,

```
sudo virsh start "VM-Name"
```

This apparently starts the VM, but no window opens and I have to open the Virt-Manager machine manually.
I want to run a single command and have the VM in a window appear.

Eventually I want to attach this command to a key binding on my i3 install and have it open with one keystroke.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a `virt-manager` command analog to the `virt-viewer` command from [cas' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/704334/537003):

```
# start the VM
virsh --connect qemu:///system start "VM-NAME"
# connect to the VM
virt-manager --connect qemu:///system --show-domain-console "VM-NAME"
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that's possible.   `virsh` and `virt-manager` are both front-ends for controlling `libvirtd` - the former is a CLI interface, the latter a GUI interface.

You could run something like `sudo virsh start "VM-Name" && virt-viewer "VM-Name"`.  And, of course, you could write a shell function or script to do that.  For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo virsh start "$1" && sudo virt-viewer "$1"
```

Note that this won't start `virt-manager` itself, it will just start `virt-viewer` (which is very similar to virt-manager's GUI console for your VM, but lacking several useful features like menu options or buttons to Reboot or Power Off the VM).  If you wanted to make use of virt-manager's other features, you'd have to run that separately.

---

BTW, it's possible to run `virsh` and `virt-viewer` without `sudo`, depending on how libvirtd is configured on your system, and what group(s) your user account is a member of.

For example: on my Debian system, my user account (`cas`) is a member of the `libvirt` group.  That allows me to run the following:

```
virsh --connect qemu:///system start VM-NAME &&
  virt-viewer --connect qemu:///system VM-NAME
```

You've mentioned arch-linux in your tags, so you should read https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Libvirt for details on how libvird is set up on arch.

Comment: I had to first add myself to the libvirt group with `sudo usermod -a -G libvirt user` then I managed to get it all working thanks to this, `#!/bin/bash
virsh --connect qemu:///system start vm-name; virt-viewer --connect qemu:///system vm-name` then added `bindsym $mod+Shift+w exec /home/user/folder/vm-name.sh` to my i3 config. It now starts and opens a window with a single keybinding. Also, I added `assign [class="Virt-viewer"] $ws4` to my i3 config which opens it in a predetermined workspace. Don't forget to run `chmod u+x /home/user/folder/vm-name.sh` to make it executable.